# AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest upload with custom headers giving 403

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, afnetworking

I've been having some problems with my AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest and AFNetworking's NSMutableURLRequest. I can successfully upload a file with just the `Content-Type` header. However, if I add the `x-amz-acl` and the `x-amz-server-side-encryption`, the upload will fail with 403 - No Permission error. What can I do? Is it an Amazon side problem, using server-side encryption or ACLs isn't allowed with pre-signed URLs, or changing the request will work? I looked pretty deep on the AWS documentation and the iOS SDK reference, but nothing on this. By the way, I'm using AWS iOS SDK v2. Does anyone how how to do this?

```
    NSString *keyName;
    NSString *fileContentTypeStr;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM.d.h.mm.ss"];
    if([multipleFileType isEqualToString:@"PNG"])
    {
        fileContentTypeStr = @"image/png";
        keyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%@.png", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    }
    else if([multipleFileType isEqualToString:@"JPG"])
    {
        fileContentTypeStr = @"image/jpeg";
        keyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%@.jpg", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    }
    self.imageUploadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image"]];

    [imageData writeToURL:self.imageUploadURL atomically:YES];
    AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest *getPreSignedURLRequest = [AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest new];
    getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BUCKET-NAME/%@",  folderObject.objectId];
    getPreSignedURLRequest.key = keyName;
    getPreSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = AWSHTTPMethodPUT;
    getPreSignedURLRequest.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];
    getPreSignedURLRequest.contentType = fileContentTypeStr;

    [[[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder] getPreSignedURL:getPreSignedURLRequest]
     continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
         if (task.error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
         } else {
             NSURL *presignedURL = task.result;
             NSMutableURLRequest *URLRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:presignedURL];
             [URLRequest setValue:fileContentTypeStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
             [URLRequest setValue:@"AES-256" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-amz-server-side-encryption"];
             [URLRequest setValue:@"private" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-amz-acl"];
             URLRequest.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";
             URLRequest.HTTPBody = imageData;

             AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
             NSProgress *progress;
             NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:URLRequest progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
             if(!error){
             NSLog(@"File was successfully uploaded.");
             }
             }];
             [uploadTask resume];
         }
         return nil;
     }];
```

Note: The code sample there lacks a few things that are on the global headers, and a few other completion blocks + delegates, but I believe everyone will understand the point here.

Anticipated thanks,

Comment: These additional headers also need to be signed by `AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder`; however, it currently does not support them. So, 403 is expected. I'll internally share this as a feature request. Thanks.

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda How do we set the ACL then??

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk There's no way, apparently.

Comment: As Gabriel mentioned, currently there is no way to set ACL through `AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder`. All Amazon S3 resources are private by default. If you want to change the permission of an object, you need to use `AWSS3` to update the permission.

Comment: You should take a look at [`putObjectAcl:`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3.html#//api/name/putObjectAcl:). Also, please make sure to check out [AWS Mobile SDK Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/) for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @YosukeMatsuda noticed in comments you can use `putObjectAcl:` method.

I put ACL for uploaded object on URLSession didCompleteWithError: delegate method like this:

```
//
self.awss3 = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:__your_config__];
//

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"S3 UploadTask: %@ completed with error: %@", task, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
//      AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest does not contain ACL property, so it has to be set after file was uploaded to bucket
        AWSS3PutObjectAclRequest *aclRequest = [AWSS3PutObjectAclRequest new];
        aclRequest.bucket = @"your_bucket";
        aclRequest.key = @"your_key";
        aclRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPublicRead;

        [[self.awss3 putObjectAcl:aclRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *bftask) {
            if (bftask.error)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error putObjectAcl: %@", [bftask.error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else
            {
                AWSEndpoint *endpoint =  self.awss3.configuration.endpoint;
                NSURL *publicReadURL = [[endpoint.URL URLByAppendingPathComponent:backgroundUploadTask.bucket] URLByAppendingPathComponent:backgroundUploadTask.key];
            }
            return nil;
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We added [`- setValue:forRequestParameter:`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest.html#//api/name/setValue:forRequestParameter:) to `AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest`. You can use this method to add ACL and encryption headers.

Also, we introduced a new `AWSS3TransferUtility` for simplifying the background transfer. Refer to our [blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx283AGGIL76PKP/Amazon-S3-Transfer-Utility-for-iOS) for more details.

Comment: tried to use that, myAwsReq.setValue("authenticated-read", forRequestParameter: "x-amz-acl"). Upload goes through and all, but, ACL is not set to "authenticated-read".